# Wordpress custom plugin release declined of the reason 'Calling core loading files directly'

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have developed a plugin for myself and was using it for a little and after decided to go public. But the plugin got declined after submission and code review with the reason ##Calling core loading files directly. I fixed already all issues they mentioned, but only one bothering me now. I have `require_once( ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );` in few places to use dbDelta(), but if I will remove `require_once` declaration I won't be able to use dbDelta(). Do you think it will be an issue with second code review? Any developer who already did and released their plugins?

Comment: "Usually plugins will include wp-config.php or wp-load.php in order to gain access to core WordPress functions, but there are much better ways to do this" I wonder if this is deemed "ok"

Answer (score 3):

**Short and simple**:

It shouldn't be an issue.

**Longer Answer**: [`dbDelta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/dbdelta/) is a function that's kind of a special case, because the "core file" (upgrade.php) that defines it isn't always going to be loaded when it's needed by your plugin.

If it's a simple query, you could probably just use a prepared statement with [`$wpdb`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). However if `dbDelta()` is indeed better for your needs (and it sounds like it is), it's *absolutely okay* to use `require_once` with `upgrade.php`, despite it technically being a core file.

Take a look at the official [Creating Tables with Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Creating_or_Updating_the_Table) codex page that literally tells you to go ahead and use it in this manner:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $sql );
```

With the reasoning:

> [...] we'll use the dbDelta function in wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php (we'll have to load this file, as it is not loaded by default) [...]

So, `require_once` away my friend!

Comment: Ok, cool! I will go with dbDelta for now, but if they will decline it again, I will have to change the query to use wpdb

Comment: If it get declined solely for that reason - be sure to point them to that codex page and ask for an alternative suggestion. However, since it's a recommended practice for that particular function, I wouldn't worry about it!

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty, great news!

Plugin got approved and it's already public :)

Thank you, everyone, for the recommendations!

You can release your plugin php code with `require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );`